# Understanding Lemma 15.19 of the Gortz's Algebraic Geometry ( Second question : injectivity of a morphism under some condition )

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

I am reading the Gortz's Algebraic Geometry Lemma 15.19 and stuck at showing some reductibility of schemes to be reduced. ( I've edited this question a bit and deleted the question I proposed in the first place. )

> Lemma 15.19. Let $X$ be a scheme with finitely many irreducible components $X_1, \dots , X_n$ and let $f:X\to Y$ be a separated morphism. If there exists a covering $X=\cup_{i\in I}U_i$ by dense open subsets $U_i \subseteq X$ such that for all $i$, $f|_{U_i}$ is an immersion (resp. an open immersion), then $f$ is an immersion (resp. an open immersion).

*Proof.* It suffices to show that $f$ is **injective** ( I understood this statement. If needed, I'll upload proof ). **We may assume that $X$ and $Y$ are reduced.** Replacing.. (omitted).

I am struggling with understanding the bold statement ( reductibility to the reduced case for $X$ and $Y$ ). My first strategy is as follows : endow the closed reduced subscheme structure on $X_j$ and $\overline{f(X_j)}$ for each $ 1 \le j \le n$.  Then each $f|_{X_j}^{\overline{f(X_j)}}$ is separated. For each $j$, define $I_j:=\{i\in I : U_i \cap X_j \neq \varnothing\}$. Then $X_j = \cup_{i\in I_j}(U_i \cap X_j)$ is a covering by 'dense' open subsets of $X_j$ since $X_j$ is irreducible space. If we can show that "for each $i\in I_j$, $(f|_{X_j}^{\overline{f(X_j)}})|_{U_i \cap X_j}$ is an immersion" (true? can we show this?), then by the reduction assumption, each $f|_{X_j}^{\overline{f(X_j)}}$ is an immersion, in particular, $f|_{X_j}^{\overline{f(X_j)}}$ is injective.
**From this, can we show that $f$ is injective?** If so, then we are done. This argument seems to work?

Or..is there any other route to show that "We may assume that $X$ and $Y$ are reduced" ?

**EDIT** ( Further attempt ) : I am still struggling with showing the injectivity of $f$ from "each $f|_{X_j}^{\overline{f(X_j)}}$ is immersion (so that injective) ". Is it possible? I've been trying to prove the simplest(?) case, i.e., $X = X_1 \biguplus X_2$ is a disjoint union of two irreducible components, with generic points $\eta_1, \eta_2$ respectively and assume that there exists open cover $X = U_1 \cup U_2$ of dense open sets, with property that each $f|_{U_i}$ and $f|_{X_j}$ are immersion. To show the injectivity of $f$, let $x, y$ be different elements of $X$. If $x, y \in U_1$ or $x,y \in U_2$ or $x,y \in X_1$ or $x,y \in X_2$, since each $f|_{U_i}$ and $f|_{X_j}$ are immersion (so are injections), $f(x) \neq f(y)$. So we consider next case : $x\in U_1$ and $y\in U_2$ and $x \in X_1$ and $y\in X_2$. Then in this case, $f(x) \neq f(y)$?

Even in this simple case, I still can't prove the injectivity of $f$. What should I catch? Can we use the density of $U_i$'s? How? Note that by using the density, we can show that each $U_i$ contains all of the maximal points $\eta_j$. Can we use this? And finally, can we generalize this simplest case to the case as in the Lemma 15.19? How?  Mayby, I think that there is a simpler way if we note some simple fact. And I don't know what is key point.

Can anyone help?

Comment: This claim at the start of your post has nothing to do with being able to assume $X$ and $Y$ are reduced.

Comment: @KReiser : O.K. Really? Then..how can we show the reductibility of $X$, $Y$ to the case of reduced? How do you think about my own argument? Correct? Does it seems to work? Do you have any idea? Perhaps, if you have time, can you give me your thought as a form of answer?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the question about topological spaces is no. Take a disjoint union of two copies of $\mathbb{A}^1_k$, both mapping via the identity to $\mathbb{A}^1_k$. Then, the restriction to each copy of $\mathbb{A}^1_k$ is the identity so it's injective. However, the morphism as a whole is not injective.

Note that the statement in the lemma includes an additional criterion : that the $U_i$ are dense.

Comment: Even if one adds "dense" to the hypotheses about topological spaces, the claim is still wrong. The bigger problem is that the claim about topological spaces does not in any way relate to the OP's underlying question about being able to assume $X$ and $Y$ are reduced when proving this lemma.

Comment: @David Lui : Thanks. And..I still don't know how can we deal with this problem. I am now trying to use the density of $U_i$'s. Let $x_1 \neq x_2 \in X$. If there exists $j \in J:= \{ 1,2, \dots n \}$ such that $x_1, x_2 \in X_j$, then we are done. And, how about if not ?? This case ( such an existence of $X_j$ ) always holds? Can you give me a hint?